# DataTable fnFooterCallback summing columns

Tags: jquery

I have problem with summing columns using jQuery DataTable fnFooterCallback. For example i have values in column (double fields):

2.0
3.0
4.0

I get total value in footer cell:
2.0
3.0
4.0
instead 9.0
What's wrong?

Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {

                var iTotal = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
                 for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
                    {
                        iTotal[0] += aaData[i][5];
                        iTotal[1] += aaData[i][6];
                        iTotal[2] += aaData[i][7];
                        iTotal[3] += aaData[i][8];
                        iTotal[4] += aaData[i][9];
                        iTotal[5] += aaData[i][10];
                        iTotal[6] += aaData[i][11];
                        iTotal[7] += aaData[i][12];
                    }

                 var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
                    nCells[5].innerHTML=iTotal[0];
                    nCells[6].innerHTML=iTotal[1];
                    nCells[7].innerHTML=iTotal[2];
                    nCells[8].innerHTML=iTotal[3];
                    nCells[9].innerHTML=iTotal[4];
                    nCells[10].innerHTML=iTotal[5];
                    nCells[11].innerHTML=iTotal[6];
                    nCells[12].innerHTML=iTotal[7];
            } 
        }
    );
    } );
```

Thanks for help and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is being held as a string, not as an float/integer.

Alter your calls to use Number, to correctly cast the data:

```
 iTotal[0] += Number(aaData[i][5]);
 iTotal[1] += Number(aaData[i][6]);
 iTotal[2] += Number(aaData[i][7]);
 iTotal[3] += Number(aaData[i][8]);
 iTotal[4] += Number(aaData[i][9]);
 iTotal[5] += Number(aaData[i][10]);
 iTotal[6] += Number(aaData[i][11]);
 iTotal[7] += Number(aaData[i][12]);
```

Comment: Apologies, parseFloat isn't exactly what you want, as it casts empty strings to NaN. Use Number instead; example is modified.

Comment: I modified it, but again display NaN.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I find what was wrong :)
I have:
var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');

and I had for example:

```
<th><center>${odczyt.id}</center></th>
```

when I remove center and /center both version: parseFloat and Number works :)

thanks for answers @Joe Pym